# Is it possible to show Edit Web Query window when the workbook is opened in excel

Tags: excel, excel-web-query

We have a url say:
http://www.example.com/myexcelbigdata/data.aspx which requires authentication. We want our users to be able to access this page via excel by using web query.

If I add the url as web query, it will be redirected to the login page (which is good). Then I type in username and password and login, /myexcelbigdata/data.aspx will be displayed again.

However, if I close and open the excel workbook again, the worksheet actually shows the login page (not the data page). Is there a way that excel can automatically show "edit web query" window every time the excel file is opened, so the users can provide username and password?

If possible, we don't want to use vba in excel book as customers will have to either use the excel we provide or knows how to type in the vba code.